GUI XML Editor with strict Schema enforcement
We have a schema which specifies the allowable elements, types, etc., of our XML content - I would like a tool which will allow the user to:
Important

edit the content of the XML files in an interactive manner
not able to add invalid content
where possible use a GUI so, e.g.: if the allowable values are an enumerate have a drop-down, if it is an integer with a range show a spin control, etc.
only permit those insertions/additions that are permitted by the schema
copy the contents of a component or structure and allow it be pasted but not allow save until any uniqueness rules are met
Searching
Undo
Collapse component/assembly not being worked on
Good clear error/problem messages
must be able to run on MS-Windows 7, ideally XP, 8 & 10.
If the Schema has been updated or a new one added then any now invalid values should be highlighted.
Allow loading, (and highlighting as above), existing XML files even if currently not matching their declared Schema.

Nice to have

Gratis
Open Source
Cross Platform
Create re-usable building blocks
Allow draft save while rules are not met but final save only when they are all met
Auto-save as draft
Comments
Comment out or Toggle blocks
Bookmarks or search terms in comments

